# How do you find the searched on text after we get Google search results?

Tags: google-search

How do you find the searched on text after we get Google search results? After we get to the page where is the relevant answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a link from your Google search results, and click on it to visit that website.
2. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> if you are on Mac (the same keyboard combination works for Chrome, Internet Explorer and Firefox) to display a *Find (on This Page)* search box.
3. Type the searched for text in the *Find* search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or use one of the other *Find* search box options that may be available in your web browser such as *Highlight all*.

Answer (score 1):

Using your browser's find-function is indeed the way to do this, as per the previous answer.

But be aware that the searched-on text is not necessarily included as text in all the items in your search results.

For example, if you have searched for "obscure phrase", and someone has a website that includes a picture for which the alt-text is "obscure phrase", then that website *may* be included in your search results, even though the text "obscure phrase" is not visible on the site to someone who is experiencing it through a regular web-browser and not using screen-reader software.

It's also possible that as Google's OCR of images gets better, search-results will contain images of the things you are searching for even if the specific search-text you use isn't in the image's file-name or alt-text.